# Socket remaining in LISTEN state after closing

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets

So, I opened a socket on a port, closed it, and attempted to open another. after the application semi-restarted(it unloads most of the libraries and reloads them, etc, so I'm not unnecessarily opening/closing).

I find that after I call `close()` on the socket, it does remove the socket from /proc/pid/fd, however the socket remains listening in `netstat -nlp` as such:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

(ran as root, so you can see it is not bound to my process)

It is a `SO_REUSEADDR` socket, and has `TCP_NODELAY` set.

Comment: So you didn't close it, you only thought you did.

Comment: @EJP I called close(), and the FD was unlinked from the process according to /proc and netstat -nlp, however the port is still bound in a LISTEN(not TIME_WAIT) state.

Comment: The situation you describe is very strange. My first instinct is to assume there is another process with a copy of the file descriptor, even if that means `netstat -p` is lying. I'd go back to what we used to do before we had a `-p` option on `netstat`: `lsof` and `fuser`. Specifically, `fuser -n tcp -v 80`

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley The output of `fuser -n tcp -v 80` is empty. I noticed after an hour of leaving the debugger paused, and the port still in it's odd state, it had been closed, however I had checked it every few minutes, so I'd say it lasted about 45 min before closing.

Comment: You will have to post some code, of course. The situation you describe is impossible. Presumably you are closing the wrong socket. It will be interesting to se the level of error checking in your code.

Comment: @user207421: I am sorry to revive this old thread but this situation is not impossible as I just ran into it :/ To add a few more precisions out server socket has both the SO_REUSEADDR and SO_REUSEPORT options. We initially closed the connection on server side with only `shutdown(srv_socket, SHUT_RDWR)` but I added `close(srv_socket)` after it and I still get the same behavior. Not sure if this is relevant but the client and server are the same executable (as it's a unit test) and it's running in a ubuntu2004 docker.

Answer (score -1):

So I ran into a similar issue that had the following behavior where the socket of the application remained in LISTEN state even after closing the server socket:

```
// Before shutdown
#27 72.23 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      333/RunTests
#27 72.23 tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:57412         127.0.0.1:6001          ESTABLISHED 333/RunTests
#27 72.23 tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6001          127.0.0.1:57412         ESTABLISHED 333/RunTests
// Call shutdown(srv_socket, SHUT_RDWR)
#27 72.23 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      333/RunTests        
#27 72.23 tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:57412         127.0.0.1:6001          CLOSE_WAIT  333/RunTests
#27 72.23 tcp        0      1 127.0.0.1:6001          127.0.0.1:57412         FIN_WAIT1   333/RunTests
// Call close(srv_socket)
#27 72.24 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      333/RunTests
#27 72.24 tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:57412         127.0.0.1:6001          CLOSE_WAIT  333/RunTests
#27 72.24 tcp        0      1 127.0.0.1:6001          127.0.0.1:57412         FIN_WAIT1   -
// A few ms later
#27 75.03 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      333/RunTests
```

Turns out @user207421 was right in our case: We *thought* we were closing the server socket, but in fact what was closed was the socket representing the connection with the client on the server side (the one returned by `accept()`), not the actual server socket listening for connections (the one returned by `socket()`).

So using `shutdown(clt_socket, SHUT_RDWR)` (on the client connection socket) and then `close(srv_socket)` (on the actual server socket) worked like a charm.